# how to dispaly multiple inline form an django admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have multiple models and i want to display them all on one page in django admin.
Some of these have no relationship(fk,onetoone,mm).
how i can achieve that?

```
class Category(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Industry(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class SampleImages(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/tile_images')
    category = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
    industry = models.ManyToManyField(Industry)


class SampleColor(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/tile_color')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=25)

class OrderDetail(models.Model):
    name_in_logo = models.CharField( max_length=150)
    slogan = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    describe_website_and_audience = models.TextField()
```

Comment: Are you looking to edit all of these objects simultaneously, or just have some as a reference when looking at the other (e.g. see the Samples when you are looking at the Order Detail)?

Comment: i have website where user can place order by providing (category,industry,select sample images and color and other detail). i want to show a complete order in one page.

Comment: If you are looking to have it within the Django Admin, the best thing would be to create a custom admin view, and query the relevant items in that view. You can read more about it [in the django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_urls). As a side note, how do you store the selected samples / categories on submission of the order, if you are not using an FK from the OrderDetail or associated object?

Comment: thanks i have need to update my database